# Not getting sklearn polynomial regression right

Tags: python, scikit-learn, polynomials

I understood the principle, but when I try it in action I got something weird, Can someone explain me what am i doing wrong ?

So I use this [dataset](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tkanos/polynomial-regression/master/data.csv)

With a simple code like :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

# Importing the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

X = df.values[:, 0:1]
y = df.values[:, 1:2]

poly_reg = PolynomialFeatures(degree=6)
X_poly = poly_reg.fit_transform(X)
lin_reg_poly = LinearRegression().fit(X_poly, y)

plt.scatter(X, y, color='blue')
plt.plot(X, lin_reg_poly.predict(poly_reg.fit_transform(X)), color='r')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately it produces :
[image: graph]

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: That's not too weird, your data is quite wobbly so it probably needs a polynomial with a higher order to fit it more closely. Try to increase the degree and see what happens

Comment: I tried and more I add degrees more it becomes weird, I end up with a straight line ended by a curve. (Is what bother me the most actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try spline interpolation. Here is my approach to this dataset:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures, SplineTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

x = df.values[:, 0:1]
y = df.values[:, 1:2]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, s=2)

transformer = SplineTransformer(degree=3, n_knots=10)
model = make_pipeline(transformer, Ridge(alpha=1e-3))
model.fit(x, y)

y_plot = model.predict(x)
plt.plot(x, y_plot, label="B-spline", color='red')
plt.show()
```

[image: result]

You can adjust `n_knots` to make it fitting the points better.

Comment: OMG you did it in 3 seconds, I have been there for days. Thanks very much. I will look at that SplineTransformer to understand what hapend behind the scene, Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. Splines are great for such interpolation tasks.